# Is this a typo??? ODE Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on a homework, and the following seems to be a typo, but I am not 100% sure.

The **question** states the following:

Solve the initial condition problem $x' = x^2$, $x(0)=1$, using the power series method for $x(t) = \Sigma_{k \geq 0} \ a_k\  t^k$, $\ t \in (- \epsilon, \epsilon), \ \epsilon > 0$. Then show that this formal power series solution is a real solution on $(-1,1)$ which one can extend to the maximum domain $(-1, \infty)$.

I solved the ODE using the method it requires me to use by finding the closed form of the recursive sequence of coefficients obtained from substituting the power series into the DE. The solution I get is then $\Sigma_{k \geq 0} \ t^k = \frac{1}{1-t}$, which is a real solution on $(-1, 1)$, because the LHS of my solution is a geometric series which is convergent for all $\ t \in (- 1, 1)$. In addition, I would assume that the RHS is the possible extension of the domain, since the function $f(t) = \frac{1}{1-t}$ has the domain $(- \infty, 1) \cup (1, \infty)$.

**My Problem** is the next part of the question. Clearly, both sides of the solution is not defined at $x=1$. So how could one extend the domain of the solution to the "maximum domain  $(-1, \infty)$"? In addition, the maximum domain extension would be $(- \infty, 1) \cup (1, \infty)$, not $(-1, \infty)$. Is that correct?

I have a hunch that the maximum domain stated in the question is not right, but I am not fully sure and it's very possible I am missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like they meant $(-\infty,1)$. I agree with you.

Comment: Thank you so much!